# Thread.Sleep() in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

The *MSDN* docs say `Thread.Sleep()` can be used in a *portable* class library. The compiler says otherwise. What are my alternatives besides a spin-loop? `Thread.CurrentThread.Join()` doesn't exist either.

Project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{C46B138E-CC30-4397-B326-8DD019E3874B}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>x0xtest.AVR</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>x0xtest.AVR</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile3</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Attributes\AddressAttribute.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Attributes\RegAttribute.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Attributes\ROAttribute.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Attributes\RWAttribute.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Attributes\WOAttribute.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Devices\ATMega162.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Exceptions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="IntelHexFormat.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Proxy.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ProxyBase.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ProxyBase_UploadFirmware.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\x0xtest.Comm\x0xtest.Comm.csproj">
      <Project>{F78547AC-1CA1-4ADB-9FA8-3E7DEB682240}</Project>
      <Name>x0xtest.Comm</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: What does the compiler say? A short but complete example including the error message would help.

Comment: The problem is probably in setup/config of your project, but you would be doing the users of the lib a disservice. So don't solve this problem but get rid of Sleep().

Comment: Agree with @HenkHolterman here (I think). What problem are you seeking to *solve* that makes you think that `Thread.Sleep` is the right solution?

Comment: @JonSkeet "System.Threading.Thread does not contain a definition for 'Sleep'" It's not in the intellisense either. The C# code is irrelevant. The setup/config of the project and dev machine is harder to convey. I'll update my Q with the project file. Basically, it's a PCL that targets .NET 4 and Silverlight 4. The Portable Library Tools I dled and installed yesterday by following the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). VS 2010 is SP1 with all Microsoft Updates.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am communicating with a device over RS232, and I need to do pauses.

Comment: I'm not convinced you need Sleep() to deal with COM port. Maybe look through the many SerialPort questions for other ideas.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the unfortunate side effect of "portable".  A library becomes highly portable by subtraction, removing all the parts that are unavailable on just one of the many possible targets.  That played havoc with the Thread class, it is quite devoid of any useful members.  Just 5 of them left, MemoryBarrier(), CurrentCulture, CurrentThread, CurrentUICulture and ManagedThreadId.

This might look odd, the intersection of the advertized targets certainly support more.  This is probably related to the un-advertized one.  The upcoming version of Windows 8 that will run on ARM cores.  Otherwise known as WinRT or Metro or the ".NET for Metro style apps" API, depending on what tools you use.  WinRT severely cuts down on the traditional Windows API, its System.Windows.Threading namespace is pretty empty.

This is going to generated a *ton* of questions on SO, the "Eeek, now what do I do" kind.  The possible workaround here is to burn up a dummy System.Threading.ManualResetEvent object.  It has a WaitOne(TimeSpan) method.

Fwiw, I'm personally not looking forward to programming against this library.  By far the most alarming tidbit is in the Q&A section of the link you provided:

> Q: I wanted to ask what's up with the Compile method of the
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class.
>   A: It's not supported on Windows Phone/Xbox, so it only shows up when you target Silverlight + .NET.

Ouch.  Portable, sportable.  This needs to stew for a while.  My sympathies to DevDiv in general and David Kean in particular, tough job.

Comment: I tried to find the reference for .NET for Metro, and it looks like Thread.Sleep() is in there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/d00bd51t(v=vs.85).aspx But maybe the documentation site is just retarded. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454043(v=vs.85).aspx clearly says, "The documentation for a type indicates which members are included in the .NET APIs for Metro style apps."

Comment: I guess the proper way to do it Metro-style is `await TaskEx.Delay` Is the async stuff in PCL? I'll check but guessing not.

Comment: Oh, and your excellent response begs the question, how can I configure my PCL to NOT target Metro? Presumably VS 11 offers the granulity?

Comment: I don't know these things, not until it is in my hands.  The beta for VS11 is due this month.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky `await` is completely different to `Sleep` - you might mean `.Wait()` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell it is slightly different, not completely. Thread.Sleep() pauses execution and yields to other threads, while await TaskEx.Delay pauses execution and yields to other threads and fibers. .Wait() doesn't yield to fibers just like Sleep(), but rarely do you want that.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky yes, but `await` is `ContinueWith` - which is different again - it is a callback only.

Answer (score 19):

(I 'own' the portable library project at Microsoft)

Unfortunately, this was a late change to the Portable Library project surface area that we made so that we could run and be referenced by Metro apps. One of the new things with Metro style apps, Visual Studio 11, and Windows 8 is to remove the need for apps to create and control their own threads (which is tough to get right). Instead, the idea is that you make use of language (ie `async`/`await`) and framework features (`Task`) to perform and synchronize with operations that should occur in the background.

What to use as a replacement (for example, `ManualResetEvent`, `Task.Delay`) , entirely depends on your scenario and what platforms you are targeting. Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: Wow, David Kean! I have so many questions and nasty things to say to you! To answer, what I am doing is driving an Open Source Hardware device over serial. First as a desktop app, then moved into Silverlight (using P/Invoke or Java JNI... SHAME on MS for killing RS232 support in Silverlight and Metro). On the subject of threads, I don't use them, but async/Task are not a substitute for them. Single-threaded != multi-threaded. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302(v=vs.110).aspx#threading) page still says to use Thread class for long-running tasks in Metro.

Comment: As to the PCL itself, I see a lot of senseless incompatibility. PCL should try a lot harder to be broadly compatible. It should be thicker, and emulate the bits of functionality that are 95%analagous but were 'separated at birth.' Eg, PCL doesn't have Thread.Sleep() nor Task.Delay(). It is sheer luck it has ManualResetEvent. Why not just include Thread.Sleep() and compile it as await Task.Delay() on Metro? Why no Enum.GetValues()? Why no ObservableCollection in .NET 4?! Etc, Etc. PCL is almost useless.

Comment: PCL should have 'faces' (the namespaces and classes to present to the developer) just so classic .NET doesn't become the default and only face. Then it should have what it targets. The targets should be fine-grained, not assembly-level. And there should be (some) shim code to fill gaps. Finally, it should extend to the broader .NET universe, including Micro Framework (eg Netduino)

Comment: Finally, I want to see all fundamental third-party libraries (that is, DI containers, test frameworks, etc., etc.,) targeted to PCL. I've invested a lot in learning them (and developers invested in creating them), that they should be seamlessly portable across whatever innovation MS thinks up.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We're working on improving the support, and I encourage you download Visual Studio 11 Beta and tell us what you think. As I talk about in my [channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/NET-45-David-Kean-and-Marcea-Trofin-Portable-Libraries) it's extremely difficult to have a sane portable story for platforms that are already done and shipped. Portability after the fact doesn't work in all situations, for example, up until we fixed this in 4.5, ObservableCollection didn't live in the same locations on all platforms.

Comment: We've made changes to future platform so that these seemingly 'random' missing APIs no longer occurs. For example, if you choose only '.NET 4.5' and '.NET for Metro style apps' you will get _every single_ API that is common between them, unfortunately,  it's next to impossible to do it for previous versions.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, I think you might be misinterpreting (I filed a bug internally to fix the doc) what the Metro page talks about. It's saying replace Thread usage with Task usage. Task also doesn't imply single-threaded; Task.Run, by default, will put work on the ThreadPool.

Comment: Is there a way to "compile in #ifdef statements" into a PCL? If that feature were available, it would vastly expand PCL compatibility and power without bringing in any of my other suggestions. Also, do you plan on supporting minor/deprecated platforms like .NET Micro or Silverlight?

Comment: And what if I want to set specific thread priority? As I understand, it's not good idea to change prio of a thread of Task because of a thread pool. But then how to create a thread with specific priority in PCL?

Answer (score 18):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(ms).Wait();
```

works as a drop-in replacement for

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);
```

This works fine when porting a legacy code base.

Answer (score 5):

Try waiting on a http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx with a timeout.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Task.Delay` in `System.Threading.Tasks`